# В laravel ошибка при миграци: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: laravel

В laravel ошибка при миграции:  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `santas` add constraint `santas_wards_id_foreign` foreign key (`wards_id`) references `wards` (`id`) on delete set null). Я хочу связать две таблицы между собой, но выходит эта ошибка. Мои миграции:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('santas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('ward');
            $table->foreignId('wards_id')->constrained('wards');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('wards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('santa');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Буду рад любой помощи в решение этой проблемы?

Comment: Не надо кастрировать сообщения об ошибках, их следует показывать полностью.

Comment: Проблему решил) При миграции таблица ward вызывалась позже, чем santa, поэтому происходила подобная проблема